# Monospace Chinese font

Tags: fonts, internationalization, chinese

I'm trying to write some Python code to process Chinese text, but the Chinese characters in the source code mess up the monospace font. That is, all the Latin characters are monospaced, but the Chinese characters are wider. That messes up my code's alignment.

Is there any monospace font that includes Chinese glyphs at the same width as the Latin characters?

I have tried several on Ubuntu 16.04, including DejaVu Sans Mono, FreeMono, and Noto Sans Mono, but they all have wider Chinese characters.